# Genymotion Plugin can't show in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, plugins, genymotion

Genymotion plugin download and install in my laptop and the emulater of Genymotion is properly working in Genymotion application but when i install genymotion in Eclipse IDE from Eclipse>Help>Add New Software i am add this plugin but it can't shows the Genymotion Tools for Eclipse in Eclipse..please anyone help me..Thanks in advance 
I can't find Genymotion Tools it says **There are no Categorized items** in Eclipse
[image: Genymotion tools is not available for next step]

[image]

Comment: In add new software window which link you enter

Comment: This link>> http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/

Comment: where you get this link

Comment: This link i get it from Genymotion website

Answer (score 25):

Remove the checkmark ***Group items by category***.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Lucky Actually it does! 

I wish I found this answer sooner.

Comment: It's working for me. unchecked group item then, list genymotion is listed

Comment: ya, I found it hahaha :D

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck following options available on the same screen while adding Genymotion plugin:

```
Show only latest versions of available software
Group items by category
```

After uncheck, Option to select Genymotion Eclipse Tools will be available.

Answer (score 1):

go through this hraphic tutorial to get genymotion installed on ur system.

http://techinnovators.in/install-and-configure-genymotion-best-android-emulator/

Btw, the url which u need to add new software is:
http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/

or

Have you tried the manual method?

1. Ensure Eclipse is closed.
2. Download the plugin from the Genymotion [download page](http://plugins.genymotion.com/plugins/eclipse/1.0.5/plugins/com.genymobile.genymotion.ide.eclipse.plugin_1.0.5.201507301435.jar).

Follow the steps corresponding to your operating system:

- If you have administrator rights, put the .jararchive in the   **Pluginsdirectory** of the Eclipse installation folder.
- Without administrator rights, put the .**jararchive** in the **Pluginsdirectory** of the Local Settings\Eclipse folder.

To start using the Genymotion plugin:
Click [image].
The following window opens:
[image]

In the Genymotion application field, browse for the Genymotion application installation directory:
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion

1. Click Apply and OK.
2. Click [image]to open the Genymotion Virtual Devices Manager window:
   [image]

After this I guess you know what to do...

Comment: i install genymotion in my system but problem is i can't find Genymotion tools in Eclipse Help>Install newSoftware>Add>Genymotion,http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/

Comment: Are you trying this on Win 10?

Comment: Hey Virat, please check the edit once. This info I got from Genymotion documentation only.
It will definitely solve the issue.

Comment: Don't use "Eclipse>Help>Add New Software" method.
Try the manual method. Where exactly you are getting the issue in that?

Comment: I also try the manual method that you mentioned here..but the problem is i can't find Pluginsdirectory of the Local Settings\Eclipse folder.

Answer (score -1):

Try to visit this link.

http://genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#installing-genymotion

Here all the genuineness regarding `installing` GenyMotion installation